# Load data from exported environment variables in laravel

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

The context is I currently working with laravel framework. Is it possible if I want to move all configs in `.env` file into system environment variables? so I don't need `.env` file anymore. So I will do:

```
export APP_NAME=Laravel
export APP_ENV=local
export APP_KEY=
export APP_DEBUG=true
export APP_URL=http://localhost
...
```

then remove the `.env` file. What should I do to make laravel read all configurations from exported environment variables instead of read from `.env` file? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by **system environment variables**?

Comment: it can work but be aware that it will use the environnement variables of your server process (apache, nginx ...). For apache your exports go to /etc/apache2/envvars for example.

Answer (score 1):

Can't understand why you want overhead of `environment variables` when `Laravel` itself give the functionality of accessing `.env` variables using

> env('APP_NAME')

All of the variables listed in the `.env` file will be loaded into the `$_ENV` PHP super-global when your application receives a request so alternatively you can use  `$_ENV['APP_NAME']` also.